# MySQL select where equal to multiple values

Tags: mysql, select

I have two databases, where I store who is following who and another which stores the posts the user makes.

I want to select all of the people a user is following from the following database and echo out the usernames of those who that user is following and query the posts database for posts of that user.

My problem is what if a user is following multiple users,
I echoed out of the user id's of the people this user is following and I get
44443344330

When I separate each id with commans, I get:

```
44,44,33,44,33,0,
```

so let's give that a variable of `$user_ids`;

```
$user_ids = "44,44,33,44,33,0, ";
```

the query:

```
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid = '$user_ids'");
```

but all it does is show the records of the first user id, 44.

How can I retrieve all of the records for all the users?

Answer (score 39):

The query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid IN (44,44,33,44,33,0)
```

However, you may have to rethink your data model and make sure it is normalized, so that you can express this construction directly in the databse without echoing into a comma-separated string.

Why do you have two *databases*? Do you mean two *tables*?

Answer (score 27):

Maybe you want to use `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid IN ($user_ids)
```

Comment: if the data type for the id's is set to Integers this won't work. It needs to be ($user_ids) not ('$user_ids')

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have two tables, not two databases, the easiest way to match multiple values for a specific column would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid IN (44,44,33,44,33,0)
```

*A small point that I ran into when doing this. If you are matching to a column that is of type VARCHAR(n), be sure to wrap your matching values in 'single quotes', not "double quotes"

e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE name IN ('foo','bar','alpha','beta')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two **tabels**, not databases, and that the table (lets call it "friends") which describes who is following who is like

```
table friends(
  userid
  friendid
)
```

then query to get posts posted by X's friends would be

```
SELECT
 p.* 
FROM posts p
  JOIN friends f ON(p.userid = f.friendid)
WHERE f.userid = X
```

Comment: hey what if I replace the values ... it is possible that user id has the id of my friend and friend id has my id then what will you do ?? if a person sends me a friend request and I accept then the sender will be in user id and receiver will be friend id ... can u help ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid in '($user_ids)'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var= str_replace(","," or userid = ","userid =$your_data_from_db");
```

your `myqsl_query = SELECT * FROM posts  where $var`

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the `or userid = ` version of this instead of using just `in`?